# Vuetify.js - class `.container` losts styles after `npm run build`

Tags: vue.js, grid, containers, vuetify.js

I experience problem with **[Vuetify.js](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/)** v2.2. When I use `container`, `row` or `col` classes. These styles works fine on 'dev'.
Once I build `npm run build` the project, these styles are not applied anymore.

I could use workaround noted here https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8013#issue-472862385, but as mentioned https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7978 this should not be the case anymore.

Anybody experienced the same and found official solution?

Examples below:

**Live** https://www.exchangehours.com/
[image]

**Local Dev** (sorry, no public domain)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my lack of knowledge of VuetifyJs and te Vue itself.

```
# What I used
<div class="container"> </div>  
  
# What needs to be used  
<v-container> </v-container>
```

I did not check it directly, but my bet is that tree shaking logic of VuetifyJs is the cause. Where on dev you have loaded all vue css & js but after build just needed css & js is added to chunk.js / chunk.css files.
Therefore if you do not use Vue components to create container or other grid elements, styles are not included to chunk.

So all works perfectly fine if you follow docs completely.